# Set state in React based on Java Spring request

Tags: java, json, reactjs, spring

I have a small project with React Front and Spring Java backend. For now I am trying to set a data in React "state" based on response of Spring method. This is how looks like Java method:

```
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@GetMapping("/cities")
public ResponseEntity getCity ()throws JsonProcessingException
{
    List <City> cities = cityRepository.findByName("New York");
    System.out.println(cities);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(cities));
}
```

When i tapped in browser

> localhost:8080/cities"

it looks like:

> [{"name":"New York","countryCode":null,"population":8008278,"id":3793,"district":"New York"}]

countryCode doesn't matter. It have @transient adnotation.

In React i have a state and methods looks like:

```
    class App extends Component {
    
    state = {
    population: '',
    district: ''
    }
    
    handleInputChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({
        value: e.target.value
      })
    }
    
    handleCitySubmit = e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      const API = `http://localhost:8080/cities`;
    
      fetch(API)
      .then(response => {
        if(response.ok){
      return response
    }
    throw Error("It doesn't works")
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          district: data.district
          population: data.population
    
        })
      })
console.log('District info: '+this.state.district)
console.log('District info: '+this.state.population)
}
```

But it doesn't works. District and population are still undifined. Does anyone could tell me, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is not all of your code in your App-Component.

Actually I use more function components but still, I think you need to bind your handlers:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      population: '',
      district: ''
   };
   this.handleInputChang = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
   this.handleCitySubmit = this.handleCitySubmit.bind(this);
}
```

Or just use Function-Components :)

And did you console log your responce from your first resolve? and I would prefer to use catch for error-handling.

Answer (score 0):

> I think you need to bind your handlers:

Sorry, but it doesn't works. I'll show all React and Spring classes of project below:

First, Spring:

City

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "city")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString


public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int ID;
    String name;
    @Transient
    String countryCode;
    String District;
    int population;

    public City()
    {

    }

    public City(int ID, String name, /*String countryCode,*/ String District, int Population) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
        /*this.countryCode = countryCode;*/
        this.District = District;
        this.population = Population;
    }
}
```

CityRepository

```
public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City, Long> {

List<City> findByName(String name);
```

}

CityService

```
    @RestController
public class CityService {

    @Autowired
    CityRepository cityRepository;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @GetMapping("/cities")
    public ResponseEntity getCity ()throws JsonProcessingException
    {
        List <City> cities = cityRepository.findByName("New York");
        System.out.println(cities);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(cities));
    }
}
```

React:

```
App.js

    class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       population: '',
       district: ''
    };
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleCitySubmit = this.handleCitySubmit.bind(this);
 }

state = {
  district: '',
  population: '',
}

handleInputChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    value: e.target.value
  })
}

handleCitySubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const API = `http://localhost:8080/cities`;

  fetch(API)
  .then(response => {
    if(response.ok){
  return response
}
throw Error("It doesn't works")
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({
      district: data.district,
      population: data.population

    })
  })
console.log('District info: '+this.state.district)
console.log('Population info: '+this.state.population)
}


  render (){
    return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form 
      value = {this.state.value}
      submit = {this.handleCitySubmit}
      />
      <Result/>
    </div>
  );
    }
}

export default App
```

Form.js

```
    const Form = props => {
return (
    <form onSubmit={props.submit}>
        <input 
        type ="text" 
        value = {props.value}
        placeholder="Enter city name"
        />
        <button>Find city </button>
    
    </form>
)
}

export default Form
```

Result.js

```
const Result = () => {
return (
    <div>City</div>
);
}

export default Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

setState is an asynchronous operation, which means it is entirely possible that those console.log calls are made before the state is properly set. The same applies to your render method. I'm not sure what your specific error is, but undefined problems using http requests are usually caused by trying to render something that depends on the state, while the state has not been set yet. In your case, it is probably that your state has not been set yet. You can try:

```
  render (){
    return (
    <div className="App">
      {this.state.value ? <Form 
      value = {this.state.value}
      submit = {this.handleCitySubmit}
      /> : <h1>State has not been set yet</h1>}
      <Result/>
    </div>
  );
    }
```

Which checks whether this.state.value actually has a value other than null or undefined, and only renders the Form when it actually has a proper value.

PS: Your indentation (or rather lack of indentation) makes your functions hard to read. I would recommend using your IDE's formatting tool to properly indent, so the code becomes easier to read for others.